# Force button to reload page after opening new window

Tags: javascript

I have a button delivered by outside company (Telerik) and It does contain some events, like one opening new window.

The thing I also want it to do is to refresh the window:

- button got clicked
- some built-in events fire (including open window)
- the page button is on refresh itself

I tried to add a new event, but page refreshes itself and the new window is not appearing.

```
if (Button.addEventListener) {                                          
    Button.addEventListener("click", ReloadPage, false);
} else {                                            
    Button.attachEvent("onclick", ReloadPage);
}
```

In some other place:

```
function ReloadPage() {
    Location.Reload();
}
```

I tried to Google topics like "force event to fire as last" or "interval still going after changing the window" but I couldn't find something that might work ON IE8 without jQuery.

What event can I add that will refresh the page without touching existing events without jQuery on IE8?

Edit:
I also tried to reload some part of window, but then I got an error from button producers script.

```
var TempContainer = ElementsContainer.innerHTML;
        ElementsContainer.innerHTML = TempContainer;
```

Edit2:
It looks like vicious circle:
-if window with button refreshes, all the other events (like open new window) are being canceled
-if new window appears, old one looses its focus (I think) and reload event is canceled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ReloadPage() {
setTimeout(function(){
 location.reload();
},0);
}
```

Use setTimeout to append to qeue...

Comment: does not work :( after second (new) window apears nothing happens

Comment: Yes, console says that object does not handle this method or function (translated from polish). Funny thing is it points for empty place in my code. IE8... However without your code I had no errors, so I think It might be the problem for this browser.

Comment: @arkadiusz maybe IE8 does not support bind... can you try the edit?

Comment: It refreshes the page, but does not open new window :( Looks like refreshing cancels all other events

Comment: @Arkadiusz can you find out the *open new page* code? That would be necessary to resolve this...

Comment: @Arkadiusz alternatively, you can increase the timeout to 2000 maybe, so that it fires after 2 seconds?

Comment: The native script has 30K lines of code (it's something WPF-like stuff).

Comment: Ok, your code with 2000ms works, but after refreshing new window disappears, so the problem might be unsolveable. Thank you anyway! I'll mark your answer as correct, because It certainly works.